# Store data of link clicked using PHP and transferring it to new page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a web application that allows a student to register through an HTML form (completed this portion) and stores their data in a DB(completed). I am using PHP/MYSQL to write this.

The idea is that I have a 'backend' will allow an admin to search for a student by either first, last, or full name (this is completed) and display a list of students on the next page. (Also completed).  The list of students will be individual hyperlinks.

My page layout is:

**backendhome.php**

- Has search bar and search button

**search.php**

- When search is clicked, will execute this page which takes the item searched and finds it in the database
- spits out data found for all students with that first/last/full name (may be multiple students) - these are hyperlinks

**code snippet search method I use on search.php**

```
 <?php
    $query = $_POST['query']; //gets value sent over from search 
     $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 
        // changes characters used in html to their equivalents, for example: < to &gt;

        $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
        // makes sure nobody uses SQL injection

        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students
            WHERE (`firstName` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`lastName` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

  if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

            while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            // $results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results) puts data from database into array, while it's valid it does the loop
                echo "<a href='studentData.php'>".$results['firstName']." ".$results['lastName']."</a></br>";
                // posts results gotten from database you can also show id ($results['id'])
            }

        }
        else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";
        }
  ?>
```

**studentData.php**

- when a student name is clicked on from search.php it will come to this page and display their data: name, email, program, id, etc.

**What I want to achieve:**

You click on the students name and it will generate a new php page with student information 
I have the basic steps in mind:

1. Store data of link clicked
2. Take data to search for student in DB
3. Display information on studentData.php

The part I am finding very difficult is taking the clicked link, storing the name between the `<a></a>` tag and transferring it to the new php page so I can do more with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your student id as mentioned below, and get that `id` in studentData.php page and retrieve student information and display it.

```
echo "<a href='studentData.php?id=".$results['id']."'>".$results['firstName']." ".$results['lastName']."</a></br>";
                         .......^
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I extracted the url then used substring to get my id. Now I can continue forward with this project!